# copy WinXP Home recovery files to new SSD

Tags: windows-xp, ssd

My wife's Samsung netbook, which has Windows XP Home Edition OEM and a 5400 SATA 2 HDD, has finally crawled to (almost) a halt, and I've decided to install an OCZ SSD into it. The problem is that the machine came with no recovery media, but the recovery partition exists and I can boot into it.

How can I go about creating a bootable DVD from that partition, and then boot off that to install on the SSD?

*NOTE:* My aim after this is to upgrade to Windows 7 Home Premium, as the upgrade option is a lot cheaper than purchasing a retail or DSP equivalent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any good RESTORE software for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/110944/is-there-any-good-restore-software-for-windows) Just create a full disk image and restore that using Acronis or similar.

Comment: Hi, I understand that, but other than finding the appropriate software tool for the job, my main concern is whether or not I'll be able to use that image on a new SSD?

Comment: Programs like Acronis generally tend to mention migration of the OS from one drive to another as part of their feature set. Worst case scenario - the OS won't boot due to a bad/missing bootloader, which a Windows DVD/rescue disc will easily fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got a potential solution:

- [Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx)
- Windows Preinstallation Environment (Windows PE) 2.0 Rescue disk
- [Youtube video: How to Clone and Backup Windows with Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWM79HCzdDA)

Looks promising (and free!). I won't mark this as the answer just yet until I do it later this evening. Will post back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) (or similar) to clone your drive, you may need to resize the partition first.
You can use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start) to do both the resize using Gparted, this should move the Windows files, and then use Clonezilla (built in to Parted Magic) to copy to the new drive
You can then run the recovery if needed.

Also when you upgrade to Win 7 you should be able to just do a full install anyway.